# Cannot cut multiple shapes from canvas

Tags: html, canvas

I am trying to cut certain pattern from file based canvas and i need multiple geometrical shapes used.

For that, i am drawing shapes on that canvas using globalCompositeOperation set to XOR.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://cimsec.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/adriatic-sea-horizon-igor-voljc.jpg';
var width = img.naturalWidth/2; // this will be 300
var height = img.naturalHeight/2; // this will be 400

document.getElementById('canvas').width = width;
document.getElementById('canvas').height = height;
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, width, height);
 
}
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";


function circle(x, y, radius)
{     
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);   
ctx.fill();
}

var iks = width/2;
var sr = width/5;
var igrek = (sr);

circle(iks,igrek,sr);

var igrek2 = 3.5*sr;
circle(iks,igrek2,sr);

});
```

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }
body {background-color:blue}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> 



<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunetly, it does not work correctly if i try cut more than one shape. On example on [litewave](http://liveweave.com/SiVz1a) only second shape is cut correctly, first one only has its perimeter cut.

Ultimately i plan to have ths shape cut from image, white area on this jpg example shoudl be transparent:
http://www.detroitbodyproducts.com/media/wysiwyg/hide.jpg

Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ctx.beginPath();` first, or else it doesn't work:

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {


var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'http://cimsec.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/adriatic-sea-horizon-igor-voljc.jpg';
var width = img.naturalWidth/2; // this will be 300
var height = img.naturalHeight/2; // this will be 400

document.getElementById('canvas').width = width;
document.getElementById('canvas').height = height;
img.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0, width, height);
 
}
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = "xor";


function circle(x, y, radius)
{     
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);   
ctx.fill();
}

var iks = width/2;
var sr = width/5;
var igrek = (sr);

circle(iks,igrek,sr);

var igrek2 = 3.5*sr;
circle(iks,igrek2,sr);

});
```

```css
.lw { font-size: 60px; }
body {background-color:blue}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<title>HTML5, CSS3 and JavaScript demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Start your code here -->

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas> 



<!-- End your code here -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It helped, thank you. But there is also onemore thing, when i load this script forst time (without cache in browser), window is empty, it starts working only when i refresh site.

Comment: I'd recommend putting everything after the `img.src='...'` line inside the `img.onload` callback. The image at the time has no size, so the canvas is also set to have no size.

Comment: I did that, but it still loads only after refreshing if cache was empty.

Comment: It loads for me even with an empty cache. It might be worth posting a new question, as it seems to be a separate issue.